# Same needle shows Hydrophobic and hydrophilic behaviour just by changing orientation or position (from surface to bulk)

Tags: surface-tension, capillary-action

If I penetrate water's surface with needle (using hand) then Cohesive forces> Adhesive forces and water molecules climb up the needle (exactly like capillary action) and needle behaves hydrophilically and when I make it rest like mosquito's legs on water, it floats (mosquitos actually float on water due to surface tension and hydrophobic nature of legs), the needle behaves hydrophobically and Cohesive forces> Adhesive forces in this case. So, my questions is, Is hydrophobic and hydrophilic nature orientation and position dependent (like whether needle is in bulk after penetrating "skin" of water or at surface like mosquito's leg)?

Answer (score 0):

If the microscopic texture of the *inside* and the *outside* of the needle are not the same, it will exhibit different *wettability* on those two surfaces.

Wettability is also extremely sensitive to adsorbed monolayers of stuff, which can turn an otherwise wettable surface unwettable. Strip the monolayer off and the surface becomes wettable again. An example of this is C16 thiol on gold in the presence of water-based solutions. This means you have to be certain that the inside and outside of the needle are both atomistically clean.

In surface tension tests like capillary lift in fine-bore needles, cleanliness is enforced at the start of every test run by heating the needle in a bunsen burner flame until it glows, then allowing it to cool in air.

Comment: I didn't asked that, I asked why the same exact needle shows Hydrophobic and hydrophilic behaviour based on orientation.

Comment: there should be no orientation effect. if you observe one, you must check to see if any of the conditions I explained are present.